# IE alert showing by default warning image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, user-interface

Here is my issue with IE.I am showing an success message in  alert after clicking an button on my webpage .

`document.alert("sucess")` showing an plain message in alert in all browsers,but in Internet Explorer its showing an warning image .

is there any way to hide that image ..it's very nasty that showing an success message with an warning image ..

Comment: check the link in IE and non IE browser :http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the icons or hide them sadly.
What you can do it create your own alert box;

```
window.alert=function( alertMessage )
{
    var alertBox = "";
            alertBox +="<div style=\"width:350px;height:70px\" class=\"alertBoxIn alertPosition\" >";
    alertBox  +="<img src=\"http://www.imsearch.info/images/info.png\" style=\"position: relative; top: 1%; left: 2%; height: '40px'\" /></td>";
                     alertBox +="<SPAN style=\"position: relative; top:-30%; left: 12%\">"+alertMessage+"</SPAN>";
                     alertBox  +="<input style=\"position: relative; top:20%; left:10%\" type=\"button\" value=\"    Ok      \" onclick=\"closeAlert();\" />";
            alertBox+="</div>";
    document.getElementById("alertPanel").innerHTML = alertBox;
    document.getElementById("alertPanel").focus();
 }
```

Check reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2007/03/03/cusomizing-the-alert-confirm-messages-in-ie.aspx